# How to add a custom button to Magento 2 product page

Tags: magento2

I want to add a custom button beside the "Add to Cart" button in product page, the button I can add custom link, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What will be the use of that button?

Comment: I want to add a custom link to this button, like an Amazon link or Ebay link

Comment: How do you get the amazon or ebay url of the product?

Comment: Adding a product attribute URL in backend, place a link for each product

Comment: For ebay different attribute and for amazon different attribute?

Comment: No, one attribute is ok for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the below file:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

to your theme like below:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

and add the below code:

```
<div class="actions">
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
            class="action primary tocart"
            id="product-addtocart-button">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
    </button>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
    <a class="primary action" href="<?= $_product->getCustomLink() ?>"><?= __('Custom Button') ?></a>
</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="actions">
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
            class="action primary tocart"
            id="product-addtocart-button">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
    </button>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
</div>
```

I have just added the line:

```
<a class="primary action" href="<?= $_product->getCustomLink() ?>"><?= __('Custom Button') ?></a>
```

after:

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
```

In my case link attribute is custom_link. You need to replace it according to your attribute.

Comment: but how to get product attributes if its configurable products in magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button in addtocart.phtml file in catalog module.

Copy file from below location

> vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

paste the file at below location

> app\design\frontend\Theme_Package\Theme_Name\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I want to add a custom link to this button, like an Amazon link or Ebay link, how can I add it?

Comment: you can hide the add to cart button and add a new anchor tag with your target URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the button in addtocart.phtml file

at

vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

```
  <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
             <button type="button"  title="whatpp" class="action primary"
             onclick=" window.open('https://wa.me/0000000000?text=I want to order this product *<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>* Price <?php echo $_product->getPrice() ?> Link <?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ;?>/ ')"><span><span><i class="icon-whatapp"></i>Order On Whatsapp</span></span></button> 

        <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.quote" template="Prac_AnsWer::getquote.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```