# Add new button in product page in M2

Tags: magento2, product, product-page, custom-button

Does anyone know how we can add new custom button beside Addtocart button on product page. 
The button I can add custom link, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I tried [How to add a custom button to Magento 2 product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241758/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-magento-2-product-page) but doesn't help alot

Answer (score 0):

**Simply:** in your product page:

```
<button type="button" class="custom-product-link" onclick="location.href='your-link-here'"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Custom')) ?></span></button>
```

If you want to call a module controller:

```
onclick="location.href='<?= $block->getUrl("frontname/controllerfolder/controllername"); ?>'"
```

Comment: Can you post the file path here

Comment: Enable the path hints like this : `Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes` Then you'll see the path